# Bootstrap doesn't work on IE 6 inside Iframe

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, internet-explorer-6

I'm working with an old system.

To not waste time understanding the old HTML code, i'm using bootstrap inside one Iframe.

This is how this page are suposed to be. On Google Chrome is working perfectly.

[image: Iframe Working on Google Chrome]

As you can see, the RED area is my Iframe, working with CSS.

```
style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border:none;"
```

On IE6 the history changes.

[image: Iframe not working on IE6]

IE don't accept any code for width and height. I have already tryed this JavaScript code as well, with no sucess.

```
function autoResize(id) {
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if (document.getElementById) {
        newheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width = (newwidth) + "px";
}
```

As you can see, the Width and Height is my first problem. The Bootstrap is not showing properly inside the iframe as well.

I need a hand to find a way to fix that.

Comment: IE6. Believe me, i need that working on IE6. -_-

Comment: I don't think Bootstrap even supports IE6. Hell, I don't think *anything* on the internet supports IE6 anymore.

Comment: as per bootstraps website they support IE8-IE11.  http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: The company I'm in, offers systems for the Brazilian government, and the computers are old, most running Windows XP with IE6 and IE8 some. In IE8 I could settle and adapt, but in IE6...... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would answer your question.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I forgot that you can use HTML markup in answers.